Adverbial clause as main clause vs verb modifier

Because she studies regularly, Nina will graduate with excellent grades.

Because she studies regularly is giving the answer 'why'.
According to me, it is modifying the verb 'graduate'. And it's answering why.
On the other hand, it is said that that the subordinate clause is modifying the whole clause. But how?

To be honest Salim, these questions are getting a little bit tiresome and repetitive. I don't think you are learning anything at the moment,  I suggest going and studying something else for a while.  Come back to this topic in six months when you are refreshed. ....   In this particular example, does it matter?  I strongly say no.  If person A thinks it "modifies the whole clause" and B think "it modifies the verb", are person A and B able to communicate, do they understand this equally.  I say "yes", so it doesn't matter.

If, on the other hand, you are interested in the grammatical structure of languages, then I strongly suggest investigating your native language and not English.  After all, subordinate clauses exist in your language too. You won't then be hampered by not knowing the language well.

But anyway, please try drawing a tree for this sentence and include it in your question.
